# Update multiple rows using for loop and array php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, for-loop

I have this code:

```
$id1=array($aa1,$aa2,$aa3,$aa4,$aa5,$aa6,$aa7);
$rank1=array($a1,$a4,$a7,$a10,$a13,$a16,$a19);
require_once("connection.php");
for($i=0;$i<7;$i++){    
   $sql = "update live_tracking set swim_rank = '"$rank1[$i]."' where id = '".$id1[$i]."'";
}
```

I want to update multiple rows of my mysql database but using the code above only the first index is being updated. Any suggestions?

Comment: you need to execute within the loop.

Comment: where you are executing the query..this is only query..

Comment: how? do you have samples?

Comment: this is my connection.php
require("constants.php");

$con = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USER,DB_PASS,DB_NAME);

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

Comment: Because you have `where id=$id` you should have `where id > $min AND id < $max`

Comment: my id1[] array consist of id that I have to be updated.

Answer (score 1):

You can execute one query only by using this :

```
$sql = "update live_tracking set swim_rank = '".$rank1[$i]."' WHERE id IN (";
for($i=0;$i<7;$i++){    
   $sql .= $id1[$i].",";
}

$sql .= ")";

$query = mysql_query($sql) or die("error : ".mysql_error());

if($query){
   echo "success";
}
```

Comment: how can I execute multiple query?

Comment: if you inclue `mysql_query()` inside for loop as proposed by other answers, you will have multiple queries. But if you use the above answer, you will have one query statement so one query to execute.

Answer (score 0):

Execute the query within the loop itself.

```
    for($i=0;$i<7;$i++)
    {    
    mysql_query("update live_tracking set swim_rank = '".$rank1[$i]."' where id = '".$id1[$i]."'");
    }
```

Comment: echo the query and execute it in database to check whether there is fields corresponding to it

Comment: how can I do that? I am just new to php

Comment: are you using phpmyadmin?

Answer (score 0):

I can see an error in the sql

```
$sql = "update live_tracking set swim_rank = '"$rank1[$i]."' where id = '".$id1[$i]."'";
```

The above should be

```
$sql = "update live_tracking set swim_rank = '".$rank1[$i]."' where id = '".$id1[$i]."'";
```

You were missing .  in '".$rank1[$i]."'

Comment: did u use mysql_query($sql) inside the loop u need to add this as well.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are on right track. but you need to execute query in the loop. like this:

```
$id1=array($aa1,$aa2,$aa3,$aa4,$aa5,$aa6,$aa7);
$rank1=array($a1,$a4,$a7,$a10,$a13,$a16,$a19);
require_once("connection.php");
for($i=0;$i<7;$i++){    
   $sql = "update live_tracking set swim_rank = '".$rank1[$i]."' where id = '".$id1[$i]."'";
   if(!mysql_query($sql)){
      echo "not updated".$id1[$i]; exit();  
   }


}
```

Comment: not updated1. That is what being echoed. How can I fix this. This is for my thesis.

Comment: you can echo  `$sql` variable and run the output query in your mysql server

Comment: how? can you elaborate more?

Comment: how can I run my query in my sql server? Do you have examples?

Comment: are you using phpmyadmin?